# Run a create n times in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, repeat, scaffold

I want to do this:
I have a Model called Item with a field called name generated with scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold Item name:string
```

My question is: When I have to create a new Item I go in localhost/3000/new and I only can create a Item each time. How I can repeat automaticaly n times? Each time i push create I want to create n registers. Does Rails Have an easy way to do this. Thanks and sorry for my English level.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) gem and simple rake task /lib/tasks/task.rake with following code:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    make_items
  end
end

def make_items

  99.times do |n|
    name  = Faker::Name.name

    Item.create!(name: name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using loop for n times in your form.
Like:

```
<% n= 10 %>
<%= form_tag url: "/products",method: :post do|f| %>
  <% (0..n).times do |i| %>
    <label> Name </label>
    <%= text_field_tag "products[][:name]"%>
  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag "Create Products" %>  
<% end %>
```

And, in products controller, 
Write following code

```
def create
  @products = Product.create(params[:products])
end
```